# How to clear static variables in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static

I have declared a static variable in my class and I want it to be cleared after it is being used. It is of int type.

Also, is there any controller function which is called when view gets unloaded? May be I can clear the variable there.

Please let me know if more info is required.
**Update**:
I am passing a value from my view to controller. Now, when my controller has this value, I want it to be sustained. For which I am using static.
For now it has proved to be handy. I welcome suggestions for a better solution. But please do provide me solution for current question :)

Comment: Honestly, it sounds as if the variable should perhaps not be static. In my experience, static variables/fields are very rarely a good solution to a problem. They more often turn out to be problems in themselves.

Comment: What is the purpose of this static variable? Note that a static variable is not tied to a particular instance/object.

Comment: I am passing a value from my view to controller. Now, when my controller has this value, I want it to be sustained. For which I am using static.

Comment: It is against the MVC principle to pass values from view to controller. I strongly recommend, don't do that.

Comment: @mipe34 : Even if I use callback methods?

Comment: What do you mean by callback methods in MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to clear static variable - assign new value to it.

If you want to execute something prior/after controller action - use [action filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs). Custom action filter allows you to override following methods (and execute your logic there):

- `OnActionExecuting` – called before a controller action is executed.
- `OnActionExecuted` – called after a controller action is executed.
- `OnResultExecuting` – called before a controller action result is executed.
- `OnResultExecuted` – called after a controller action result is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my second question. But regarding the first one, won't assigning a new value to it be the same? I guess I put my question in a wrong way. How to deallocate or release static variable? Sorry if it sounds strange because I have recently started c#.

Comment: @Nitish: there is no way to deallocate or "release" a static variable because, well, it's static. As I mentioned in my comment, static state is very rarely a good approach. If you update your question explaining what you want to achieve, you may get better suggestions.

Comment: Make browser pass data to controller. View used only as placeholder for model's data.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you **against** using static variables in the context of a web application. Remember that many requests can be processed simultaneously by different threads, leading to really "hard to spot" bugs.

Use a static [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap your static variable in session to maintain different values per session, like this.

```
    public static Int32 MyInt
    {
        get
        {
            return (Int32)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyInt"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["MyInt"] = value;
        }
    }
```

And you won't need to clear it anymore, if this is why you want to clear the value.

Comment: Well, not the exact answer of your question ;)... You can only reassign an initial value to a static variable, can't exactly clear it as the word "clear" suggests...